# How to scale <i> tag from the center of It's parent element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an Font Awesome icon scale from the center when hovered over it. But every time I hover it, it scales and moves to the bottom right corner.

```css
.field {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 70px;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.field .fa-times {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: red;
}

.field .fa-times:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="field">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</div>
```

I expect this Times icon to scale from the center.

Comment: Fonts are not squares with equal sides so finding the center is mostly trial and error. The main properties to adjust are `line-height`, `text-align`, and `transform-origin`. See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671435/2813224).

Comment: you are overriding the translation with the scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use font size:

```css
.field {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 70px;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.field .fa-times {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: red;
}
.field .fa-times:hover {
  font-size:120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="field">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</div>
```