# CSS Animation and Generated Content not animating

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a cog icon via Unicode and I'm trying to make it spin on `focus` and `hover` events.

```css
@keyframes spin
{
  0 {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}

a[title*='important']::after {content: '\2699';}

a[title*='important']:hover::after
{
  animation: spin 5s infinite; 
  outline: #00f solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="important">link</a>
```

I added the blue `outline` to confirm that I was *selecting* correctly. Why is the CSS generated content *not* animating and how do I fix it?

---

I did some testing and found some very ironic results!

- IE11 **works**
- Chrome 72 fails.
- Waterfox 56 fails.
- Firefox 66 fails.
- Safari 11 fails.

Suggestions on getting the "slacker" browsers working?

---

**Update**

The answer by bijal to use `display: inline-block;` managed to animate the cog *however* it moves around in a circle instead of simply rotating.

If you apply a `background-color` to the pseudo-element and notice that the width is wider than you expected (e.g. a 50 pixel width for a 20px cog) use `text-indent: 0;`. If you do some other stuff with your code go in to your developer tools and start unchecking applied property/value pairs until the issue is revealed.

Comment: maybe this article can help you [https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 Nope, the animation is *not* on CSS generated content and the page only makes *claims*. I updated my question, now I sigh and presume I need to find a work around for something that should be universally supported. -_-

Comment: here is a related question where you can udjust line-height to get a perfect rotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54670339/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, try to apply display: inline-block it will work.

```
    a[title*='important']:hover::after{
      display: inline-block;
      animation: spin 5s infinite; 
      outline: #00f solid 2px;
    }
```

Comment: I can only respond with an image: https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2Fcc51f2a4f411efa5c8d5b5ca6c325b48%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D3846355&f=1

Answer (score 2):

I have done some chnages and created a pen, please check

[`Animation on hover`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/OGeryZ)

Comment: Yes, there is an issue where the element does some wonky stuff...your suggestion seems to iron that issue out though give me a little while and I'll see how we can adjust it to really keep the cog in a set location while *still* rotating it. :-)

Comment: If you have a `background-color` and notice a bunch of space (e.g. a 50px width for a 20px cog) use the following `text-indent: 0 !important;` so your suggestion helped my thinking in that direction, thank you!

Comment: I used `line-height` it makes some affect. you can check the link again.

Comment: Also for browser comparability please use `-webkit-` `-moz-` prefix.